# How can I structure my JSON schema to validate for DynamoDB and RESTAPI?

Tags: python, json, rest, amazon-dynamodb, marshmallow

I am writing a REST API that will store several complex objects to an AWS DynamoDB and then when requested, retrieve them, perform computations on them, and return a result. Here is a big of extracted, simplified, renamed, pseudo code.

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, height, weight):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

class Machine:
    def __init__ (self, widgets):
        self.widgets = widgets
    def useful_method ():
        return "something great"

class WidgetSchema (Schema):
    height = fields.Decimal()
    weight = fields.Decimal()
    @post_load
    def make_widget (self, data):
        return Widget(*data)

class MachineSchema (Schema):
    widgets = fields.List(fields.Nested(WidgetSchema))
    def make_machine (self, data):
        return Machine(*data)

app = Flask(__name__)
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", ...) 

@app.route("/machine/<uuid:machine_id>", methods=['POST'])
def create_machine(machine_id):
    input_json = request.get_json()
    validated_input = MachineSchema().load(input_json)
    # NOTE: validated_input should be a Python dict which
    # contains Decimals instead of floats, for storage in DynamoDB.
    validate_input['id'] = machine_id
    dynamodb.Table('machine').put_item(Item=validate_input)
    return jsonify({"status", "success", error_message = ""})

@app.route("/machine/<uuid:machine_id>/compute", methods=['GET'])
def get_machine(machine_id):
    result = dynamodb.Table('machine').get_item(Key=machine_id)
    return jsonify(result['Item'])

@app.route("/machine/<uuid:machine_id>/compute", methods=['GET'])
def compute_machine(machine_id):
    result = dynamodb.Table('machine').get_item(Key=machine_id)
    validated_input = MachineSchema().load(result['Item'])
    # NOTE: validated_input should be a Machine object
    # which has made use of the post_load
    return jsonify(validated_input.useful_method())
```

The issue with this is that I need to have my Marshmallow schema pull double duty. For starters, in the create_machine function, I need the schema to ensure that the user calling my REST API has passed me a properly formed object with no extra fields and meeting all required fields, etc. I need to make sure I'm not storing invalid junk in the DB after all. It also needs to recursively crawl the input JSON and translate all of the JSON values to the right type. For example, floats are not supported in Dynamo, so they need to be Decimals as shown here. This is something Marshmallow make pretty easy. If there was no post_load, this is exactly what would be produced as validated_input.

The second job of the schema is that it needs it to take the Python object retrieved from the DynamoDB, which looks *almost* exactly like the user input JSON with the exception of floats are decimals, and translate it into my Python objects, Machine and Widget. This is where I'll need to read the object again but this time use the post load to create objects. In this case, however, I do not want my numbers to be decimals. I'd like them to be standard Python floats.

I could write two totally different Marshmallow schema for this and be done with it, clearly. One would have Decimals for the height and weight and one would have just floats. One would have post loads for every object and one would have none. But writing two identical schemas is a huge pain. My schema definitions are several hundred lines long. Inheriting a DB version with a post load didn't seem like the right direction because I would need to change any fields.Nested to point to the correct class. For example even if I inherited MachineSchemaDBVersion from MachineSchema, and added a post_load, MachineScehemaDBVersion would still reference WidgetScehema, not some DB version of the WidgetSchema, unless I overroad the widgets field as well.

I could potentially derive my own Schema object and pass a flag for are we in the DB mode or not.

How are people generally handling this issue of wanting to store REST API input more or less directly to a DynamoDB with some validation and then use that data later to construct Python objects for a computation?

On method I have tried is to have my schema always instantiate my Python objects and then dumb them to the database using dumps from a fully constructed object. The problem with this is that the computation library's objects, in my example Machine or Widget, do not have all the required fields that I need to store in the database, like the IDs, or names or descriptions. The objects are made specifically for doing the computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this. Effectively, what I've done is to generate the Marshmallow schema exclusively for translation from the DynamoDB into the Python objects. All Schema classes have @post_load methods that translate into the Python objects and all fields are labeled with the type they need to be in the Python world, not the database world.

When validating the input from the REST API and ensuring that no bad data is allowed to get into the database, I call `MySchema().validate(input_json)`, check to see that there are no errors, and if not, dump the input_json into the database.

This leaves only one extra problem which is that the input_json needs to be cleaned up for entry into the Database, which I was previously doing with Marshmallow. However, this can also easily be done by adjusting my JSON decoder to read Decimals from floats.

So in summary, my JSON decoder is doing the work of recursively walking the data structure and converting Float to Decimal separately from Marshmallow. Marshmallow is running a validate on the fields of every object, but the results are only checked for errors. The original input is then dumped into the database.

I needed to add this line to do the conversion to Decimal.

```
app.json_decoder = partial(flask.json.JSONDecoder, parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
```

My create function now looks like this. Notice how the original input_json, parsed by my updated JSON decoder, is inserted directly into the database, rather than any data mundged output from Marshmallow.

```
@app.route("/machine/<uuid:machine_id>", methods=['POST'])
def create_machine(machine_id):
    input_json = request.get_json() # Already ready to be DB input as is.
    errors = MachineSchema().validate(input_json)
    if errors:
      return jsonify({"status": "failure",message = dumps(errors)})
    else:
      input_json['id'] = machine_id
      dynamodb.Table('machine').put_item(Item=input_json)
      return jsonify({"status", "success", error_message = ""})
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question.  This is great and wonderful etiquette that I wish more folks did.  Good job!